# Error : Failed to load WS-Security Policy definition from classpath resource: META-INF/policy.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I am getting error when i calling webservices java file.

Even i included the Policy.xml in that location , eventhough getting error.
Failed to load WS-Security Policy definition from classpath resource: META-INF/policy.xml

Please let me what is reason is behind ?

Answer (score 0):

META-INF/Policy.xml is not the same as META-INF/policy.xml... in your example you show that you've included it with a capital P. If that's the case, try renaming it at to lowercase 'policy.xml' and see if it works.

If that fails, open your WAR file and make sure that it's actually in the META-INF directory.